# Error: Could not find a Shiny session object

Tags: r, object, session, shiny

I am new to Shinny. I am creating an app which needs to display a bar plot.
I have the following error
The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':    box

Error: Could not find a Shiny session object
Execution halted

I was reviewing the use of session in my app and I do not see any unusual. I appreciate any help to solve this issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinydashboard)
library(graphics, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library (stats, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(stringr)


# remove all objects
rm(list = ls())


trigram <- readRDS("3gram_en.rds")
words <- list()

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(titlePanel("Text Input for Prediction"),
              
              sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                      
                      tags$b("Please type some words in the box below."),
                      textInput("textInput01", label=NULL, 
                                value = "", width=NULL,
                                placeholder=''),
                      shinyalert("shinyalert01"),
                      tags$b("The most likely input predicted:"),
                      verbatimTextOutput("verbatimTextOutput01", placeholder=TRUE),
                      tableOutput('tableOutput01'),
                      actionButton("actionButton01", "Clear Input")
                  ),
                  
                  mainPanel(
                     plotOutput("barplot01")
                  )
              ) # end of sidebarLayout()
    ) # end of fluidPage()
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    # type
    observe({
        input$textInput01 # read-only
        
        # alphabetical and lower-case only 
        text <- tolower(input$textInput01)
        text <- gsub("^[^a-z]+|[^a-z]+$", " ", text)
        text <- str_trim(gsub("\\s+", " ", text))
        
        # convert the input text to a list of words
        words <<- unlist(strsplit(text, " "))
        
        if (length(words) == 0){
            # show a message
            if (str_trim(input$textInput01) != ""){
                showshinyalert(session=session, 
                               id="shinyalert01", 
                               HTMLtext=paste0("\"", input$textInput01, 
                                               "\" isn't valid input for prediction."), 
                               styleclass="danger")
            }
            output$verbatimTextOutput01 <- renderText(NULL)
            output$tableOutput01 <- renderTable(NULL)
            output$barplot01 <- renderPlot(NULL)
            return()
        } 
        
        # show message
        showshinyalert(session=session, 
                       id="shinyalert01", 
                       HTMLtext=paste0("Words for prediction are \"", text, "\"."), 
                       styleclass="info")
        
        # perform  3-gram search dictionary
        # matching  last two words
        pred <- head(trigram[grep(paste0("^", str_trim(paste0(words[length(words)-1], " ",
                                                              words[length(words)])), " "), 
                                  trigram[,'ngrams']),], 20)
        # matching with the last word
        if (length(words)>1 & dim(pred)[1]==0){
            pred <- head(trigram[grep(paste0("^", words[length(words)], " "), 
                                      trigram[,'ngrams']),], 20)}
        
        if (dim(pred)[1]==0){pred <- trigram[1:20,]}
        
        if (dim(pred)[1] != 0){
            #  prediction output
            output$verbatimTextOutput01 <- renderText({pred[1,1]})
            # show predicted words table
            output$tableOutput01 <- renderTable(head(pred))
            # plot bar chart
                       output$barplot01 <- renderPlot({
                p01 <- ggplot(data=pred, aes(x=reorder(ngrams, -prob), y=prob)) +
                   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue") +
                    geom_label_repel(aes(label=ngrams), size=4) +
                    labs(title=" 3-gram Predicted Probability",
                         x="", y="Probability") +
                   theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30, face="bold"),
                          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                         axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90))
                print(p01)
            })  #end of renderPlot()  
            return()
        } # if (dim(pred)[1] != 0)
        
        output$verbatimTextOutput01 <- renderText("(No prediction)")
        output$tableOutput01 <- renderTable(NULL)
       output$barplot01 <- renderPlot(NULL)
        
    }) # end of observe input$typeahead01
    
    # click on "Clear Input" button
    observeEvent(input$actionButton01, {
        words <<- list()
        updateTextInput(session, "textInput01", value="")
        output$verbatimTextOutput01 <- renderText(NULL)
        output$tableOutput01 <- renderTable(NULL)
        output$barplot01 <- renderPlot(NULL)
        # show message
        showshinyalert(session=session, 
                       id="shinyalert01", 
                       HTMLtext=paste0("Input has been cleared."), 
                       styleclass="success")
        return()
    }) # end of observeEvent input$actionButton01
    
} # end of server function

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```